# Are there any configuration libraries that provide a native implementations for merging modifications found in split files (as seen in .d folders)

Tags: configuration, libraries, configuration-files

I've been having trouble sorting through the noise while trying to find an answer to this. There are certainly a lot of libraries available for handling configuration files but what I'm looking for is an answer to whether there is a solution available for this specific kind of split configuration.

On Linux systems I've found that it's not uncommon to find a program which has split its default configuration away from user modifications by instructing the user to place a subset of the default configuration into a separate folder (commonly found with a .d suffix). These changes override what is found in the default configuration and provide a very easy way to track at a later date what has been modified.

Answer (score 0):

There is a wide variety of incompatible syntaxes used across different configuration files, and I am not aware of a library that can parse them all. But if you are willing to restrict yourself to just one configuration syntax, then two answers to your question come to mind.

The first is to use a scripting language as your configuration file syntax. Let's assume an application reads both `default.cfg` and `override.cfg` (in that order). If `default.cfg` contains `name="john"`, then `override.cfg` might contain `name="mary"`, which will have the effect of overriding the value of `name`. This occurs because the shell interpreter provides a common place to store the global variables assigned within the script files. The following pseudocode shows how your application could interact with a scripting language interpreter:

```
interp = new Interpreter();
interp.executeFile("default.cfg");
interp.executeFile("override.cfg");
name = interp.getValueOfVariable("name");
```

The second is to use [Config4*](http://www.config4star.org/), which is a Configuration-file parser I wrote; it is available in C++ and Java. I recommend you read Chapter 2 (*Overivew of Config4* Syntax*) in the [*Config4* Getting Started Guide*](http://www.config4star.org/download/manuals/config4star-getting-started-guide.pdf). The "adaptive configuration" abilities of Config4* seem to fit the question I think you are asking. If, after reading Chapter 2, you agree, then read Chapter 3, which provides an overview of the C++ and Java API. That will probably be enough to get you started.